# Class 'App\Post' not found

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

I am working on **laravel** 5.2 AJAX Pagination with Jquery  I have defined my post class as

**Post.php**

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'posts';

    /**
     * Define guarded columns
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = array('id');
}
```

**BlogController.php**

```
<?php

class BlogController extends Controller
{
  /**
     * Posts
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function showPosts()
    {
      $posts = Post::paginate(5);

        if (Request::ajax()) {
            return Response::json(View::make('posts', array('posts' => $posts))->render());
        }

        return View::make('blog', array('posts' => $posts));
    }
}
```

Kindly help me where to paste this class to go right .
I know its error that model class is missing but dont know how to get rid of

[image]

My code structure is in snapshot
Thanks

Comment: share your controller function , the issue should be there, `App\Post::paginate(15)`

Comment: BlogController.php

<?php

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Posts
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function showPosts()
    {
        $posts = Post::paginate(5);

        if (Request::ajax()) {
            return Response::json(View::make('posts', array('posts' => $posts))->render());
        }

        return View::make('blog', array('posts' => $posts));
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Post.php` model should be

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    //
}
```

In `BlogController.php` file add below lines on top

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Post;
```

Read this:- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Comment: A new error after adding these lines of code
FatalErrorException in Post.php line 5:
Class 'App\Eloquent' not found
@Ravi Hirani

Comment: Please add second line also.

Comment: Still same error FatalErrorException in Post.php line 5: Class 'App\Eloquent' not found

Comment: Write class Post extends Model instead of Post extends Eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Add the namespace in the beginning of file like and use Model rather than eloquent class to extend

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model {

}
```

It will work for laravel >5.0 .

Comment: now a new error after adding 'namespace App;'
Class 'App\Eloquent' not found

@anwerjunaid

Comment: You may want to look into documentation , but here is you solution

Comment: Add your laravel version in question it will help with setting models and documentation.

Comment: @Ramzan Mahmood did you change `extends Eloquent` to `extends Model` ?

Comment: @Ramzan Mahmood why you just create a model with artisan `php artisan make:model Post
`

Comment: No i not create it with command line i added manually php file . @ ABDEL-RHMAN

Answer (score 0):

You should add below statements at top of your **Post.php** file, like this...

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Now, in **BlogController.php** add the below statement at top of the file, like...

```
<?php

use App\Post;
```

will work definitely in Laravel 5>=