# Laravel | Unable to get multiple keywords mapped to return combined results | Class 'App\Http\Controllers\API\Post' not found

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

**Issue :**

I'm trying to get multiple keywords searched in a single query, but for some reason I'm getting this error always :

```
[2020-08-29 03:50:02] development.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\API\Post' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\Post' not found at /home2/examplehat/public_html/shopper/app/Http/Controllers/API/ClassifiedSearchAPIController.php:78)
[stacktrace]
```

Here's my controller's index function :

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    { 
      
     
        try{
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new LimitOffsetCriteria($request));
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new ProductsOfFieldsCriteria($request));
            if($request->get('trending',null) == 'week'){
                $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new TrendingWeekCriteria($request));
            }
            else{
                $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new NearCriteria($request));
            }

          $queryString = $request->query;
  
        if ($queryString = $request->query('search')) {
       //     [$column, $term] = explode(':', $queryString);

       $terms = explode(" ", request('q'));

$products = Product::query()
    ->whereHas('store', function ($query) use ($terms) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            // Loop over the terms and do a search for each.
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
        }
    })
  
    ->get();
  

else
        
           $products = $this->productRepository->all(); 
    
       
        } catch (RepositoryException $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this->sendResponse($products->toArray(), 'Products retrieved successfully');
    }
```

Can someone please help me understand what needs to be done to fix the error stated ? I tried `use App\Post;` but it didn't help.

Comment: Use full namespace ```$products = \App\Post::query()....```

Comment: Tried this. Still the same error in logs..Log says : [2020-08-29 04:11:01] development.ERROR: Class 'App\Post' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code:

Comment: so where did you create this `Post` model you are referring to? what namespace did you define it in?

Comment: @lagbox : I don't see the Post model anywhere within the folders. I'm not very familiar.. Shall i create one like specified in   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593645/class-app-post-not-found ?  Pardon my ignorance, I'm just a beginer in Laravel

Comment: then how do you even know to use this `Post` model at all? what is it supposed to be, where does it come from? you have to have some reason for referencing it ... is this a typo and you are actually referring to the `Product` model that you have commented out?  :)

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to follow the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46767009/13687099 . My use-case is to be able to search for multiple keywords & return all matching .... My table name is products from which I'm trying to filter out for all keywords... i don't know if Post is mandatory or if there is any other way

Comment: did your code where you have commented out the `Product` model usage work? if so then you have a `Product` model and you should be using that ... so this seems like a typo basically and you are intending to use your `Product` model, ... just replace `Post` with `Product`

Comment: @lagbox You're right. I was suppose to use Product instead of Post. My bad, i've been following the instructions in the post without knowing the underlying story.  As of now i'm getting the result but not the use-case. So when i search for a string or array of keywords, its returning all from the table. I've updated my latest for loop search above, it would be terrific if you could share ay hints around the problem, if possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **namespace** in controller and models

**Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
```

**Model:**

```
namespace App;
```

> A name space allows you to partition code into logical groups by
> defining them into their own "namespace". A text string after the
> "namespace" keyword identifies the name space and all code below it
> then lives within that name space. Name spaces also provide a way to
> group interfaces functions and constants.

You can read more about [namespace](https://conetix.com.au/blog/namespaces-laravel-applications/).

Hope this works in your case!!

Comment: I still get   [2020-08-29 04:07:14] development.ERROR: Class App\Models\Product does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class App\\Models\\Product does n in the logs.. What do you think is wrong ?

Comment: A quick explanation on namespaces can help improve this answer